# Defining variables in c++ inline assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I am searching for a way to define variables in c++ inline assembly. I found an interesting way to do it. But it confuses me, how this can work.

```
    __asm
    {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        add esp, 4

        mov [ebp - 4], 2
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
    }
```

I see this code as - Push base pointer address to the stack, move stack pointer address into base pointer's (Stack logically should collapse here, because this is common epilogue function of cleaning the stack). Then we move 4 to the esp address (Not even the value) And then remove that 4 from esp. So we get back to the same esp address. Strange fact for me is that, it even compiles, and it works. But when I try to test it by outputting the value

```
uint32_t output;
    __asm
    {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        add esp, 4

        mov [ebp - 4], 2
        mov output,[ebp-4]
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
    }
    std::cout << output;
```

It does not compile, showing "Operand size conflict", which seems weird to me, because I use 32 bit integer and register is also 32 bit. When using [ebp-4] without [], it gives garbage values, as expected.
So, maybe someone could explain how this works without giving error :)
And one additional question, why does db does not work in inline assembly?

Comment: Code is wrong: `add esp, 4` should be `sub esp, 4`. As for the other problem, you can't do `mov output,[ebp-4]` because both are memory operands and `mov` only accepts one. You could do `mov eax, [ebp-4]; mov [output], eax` or similar. Also note that since you moved `esp` and `ebp` the compiler may generate wrong code if you refer to `output`. In short, don't try to do this.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) But what about the db? Why does it not work?

Comment: Are you writing this inside a larger c++ function or are you trying t create an entire function with inline assembly?

Comment: Related: [Defining a variable inside c++ inline assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/1396265)  - it's impossible to declare a *C++* variable in inline asm, but you can reserve anonymous space on the stack to use inside your asm.

Answer (score 2):

**It doesn't work, that doesn't define a C++ variable.**

It just messes with the stack to reserve some new storage below the stack frame created by the compiler.  **And you modify EBP so compiler-generated addressing modes that use EBP will be broken.**<sup>1</sup>

If you want to *define* or *declare* a C++ variable, do it with C++ syntax like `int tmp`.

asm doesn't really have variables.  It has registers and memory.  Keep track of where values are using comments.  If you want to use some extra stack space from MSVC inline asm, I think that's safe, but don't modify EBP if you also want to reference C++ local variables.

---

Footnote 1:

That would be the case if your code assembled at all, which it won't because `mov output,[ebp-4]` has 2 explicit memory operands.  MSVC inline asm can't allocate C++ variables in register.

Also `mov [ebp - 4], 2` has ambiguous operand-size: neither operand has a size associated with it because neither is a register.  Maybe you want `mov dword ptr [ebp - 4], 2`

Comment: If messing up with ESP is bad idea, maybe it is good to try something like [eax+4]? Then stack will not be corrupted and varriable will be in memory. Or it will not work? :D (I am new at assembly though...)

Comment: @Raicha: You have to point EAX at something, and if that's space below ESP then it's not safe.  Anyway, it *is* safe to modify ESP (the stack pointer), as long as you restore it afterwards.  Like you're doing in your answer with pushes and an equal number of pops.  It's *not* generally safe to modify EBP (which MSVC uses as the frame pointer).  Look at the compiler-generated code (disassembly or https://godbolt.org/) for a function that used inline asm to see how it uses EBP.